# Possible to disable "You have new mail in /var/mail/root"?

Tags: bash, freebsd

I would like to disable the mailcheck in FreeBSD 9.1. My login shell is BASH, so I have tried to add

```
unset MAILCHECK
```

in `/root/.bashrc` and `/root/.profile`, but I still get those messages.

**Question**

Is there a way to get rid of those messages?

Comment: Normally you would just forward `root`'s mail somewhere else (like to a mailbox you actually check) -- but the answers below are good ones if you want mail to keep going to `root`, but don't want the mail banners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Dennis' answer, FreeBSD sets the `MAIL` environment variable for all users in the `default` login class. This is in `/etc/login.conf`.

You can change this in several ways:

1. Edit `/etc/login.conf` and remove `MAIL=/var/mail/$` from the `setenv` line. You then need to compile the login database by running `cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf`.
2. Create a new login class that just applies to you, or a group of users. Set this for each user by using `pw usermod <username> -L <class>`.
3. Create a user-specific `~/.login.conf`. This file should have a record called `me`. This can override a subset of the global settings. Likewise this file needs to be compiled with `cap_mkdb`.

See [`login.conf(5)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=login.conf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) for more information on the login capabilities database.

Answer (score 6):

Those messages are probably periodic reports. It's quite common to set `daily_show_success=NO` in `/etc/periodic.conf` so it doesn't generate "all's good" messages. Also, `daily_output="$destination"` should be set to your e-mail address or a log file that you can monitor. The same can be set for `weekly_` and `monthly_` - and probably should be.

You can delete those e-mails by starting `mail`, `d *` to delete all messages, and `q` to quit.

Disabling the mail check is usually a mistake. If a daemon is configured incorrectly to deliver mail to the local root, you want to know, it might have something important to say and you'll miss those messages if you disable the mailcheck.

Answer (score 5):

That should take care of that message for root logins. If you're logging in as another user, you'll need to add that to the `~/.bashrc` of each user you want to disable it for. Or you can put it in the central startup file: `/etc/profile` to have it take effect for all users.

You will need to check to see if `MAILCHECK` is being set at a later point in the startup file sequence overriding your `unset`.

Note that the startup files are processed as follows (from the [Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files)) (emphasis mine):

> Invoked as an interactive login shell, or with --login
>
> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it **first reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.**
>   After reading that file, **it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,
>   and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from
>   the first one that exists and is readable**. The --noprofile option may
>   be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, Bash reads and executes commands from the
>   file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists. Invoked as an interactive non-login
>   shell
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash
>   reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This
>   may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option
>   will force Bash to read and execute commands from file instead of
>   ~/.bashrc.
>
> So, typically, your ~/.bash_profile contains the line
>
> if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
>
> after (or before) any login-specific initializations.

Answer (score 1):

edit the file `/etc/crontab` and change the line `MAILTO=root` to `MAILTO=""`

Source: http://michaelprogramming.blogspot.com/2014/01/disable-you-have-new-mail-in.html